# Commerce modules load only when browser debugger is open

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce

We have the commerce server setup in a remote server. When browsing the CMS from that server, the modules - `Customer & Order Manager` and `Merchandising Manager` load fine.

However, if I browser them from a local machine `http://<serverip>/sitecore/client/Applications/CustomerOrderManager/Search`, the data doesn't load.

It only shows up if the browser debugger is open. Checked in chrome & firefox.

[image]

Comment: can you check if you have addons/extensions on your local browser and try to open in incognito mode ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu It's the same in incognito. The browser has no add-ons. I have also tested by browsing another instance which is also in remote. Same issue.

Comment: Does the devtools console network tab have Disable Cache enabled? Possibly some sort of HTTP cache thing? (that setting wouldn't apply if devtools was closed)